# round function not working in python

Tags: python, rounding

how do i round off a function.

i have the following code in python

```
def round(x,n):
    return round(x,n)
```

i get the following error

```
>>> round(3,98.9898, 2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
round(3,98.9898, 2)
TypeError: round() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

i think the comma is creating the problem

any suggestions.... please thanks

i tried this.

```
def round(x,n):    
    return round(float(x.replace(",", "")),n)
```

no luck.

Comment: the number is auto generated.. so how do i remove the comma

Comment: Your "code sample" `round(3,98.9898, 2)` is unlikely to be the real code.  You're leaving something out.  Please include the **real** code.

Comment: It looks like your error is in your function call, not in the function itself.  See the edits in my answer.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you're redefining the `round` function with a call to itself?  I think you're about to hit a recursive loop once you get the syntax fixed.

Comment: Even if you remove the comma, it looks like your `def round():` function will go into recursive loop calling itself over and over. BTW, if `3,98.9898` was a string you could remove the comma with something like `s = '3,98.9898'.replace(',', '')` or `s = '3,98.9898'.translate(None, ',')`

Comment: The reason `return round(float(x.replace(",", "")),n)` doesn't work is because the problem is with the comma in the `round(3,98.9898, 2)` call. **Where** is that code coming from? If it was generated by something, it was done incorrectly because it attempts to pass too many comma-separated arguments -- three of them -- to the `round` function(s).

Comment: I edited and fixed a mistake in the formatting of your question which was hiding the fact that **you** were generating the code by typing it into the interactive console. First off, leave the comma in the first number out so it's just `398.9898`. At that point you will see another error due to how you have defined your `round()` function.

Comment: -1: `def round(x,n) return round(x,n)`  What is the point of defining a function that simply "wraps" a built-in?  `round(3,98.9898, 2)` is clearly incorrect.  I can't see how this question can ever be helpful to anyone.  Perhaps it should be revised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- `round(3,98.9898, 2)` is code that *you* enter. Omit the comma yourself and your problem goes away. Otherwise give us more info about your problem.
- `def round(x, n): return round(x, n)`
  Even if you fix your function call, you'll most likely end up with `RuntimeError` due to maximum recursion. Rename your function to something other than `round`.

Answer (score 2):

How are you getting that number? If it autogenerated, it must be a string. do a `float(number.replace(',',''))` when you are using it the `number` as an argument for round.

Comment: If it were a string, the parser wouldn't read the comma as a separator between function parameters... I think the code itself must be generated by something.

Comment: Oh yeah, possibly. Perhaps the user is seeing the auto generated string and trying out in a separate session to know about round. I can't possibly think of a situation where a comma included non-string entity is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the comma.  A number cannot have a comma in it.  Commas should only be added for display purposes, *after* all computation, which can be done after converting the number to a string.

If you're dealing with user input, it's going to be a string, and you'll have to strip out commas before converting to a float/int.

---

I'm gonna step back and start with the basics.  Is this your actual code?

```
round(3,98.9898, 2)
```

If so, you are passing three parameters into the function: `3`, `98.9898`, and `2`, but the function only accepts two.  Perhaps you mean one of the following:

```
round(98.9898, 2)
round (398.9898, 2)
```

or some other variation?

Comment: @user: We can't possibly know. We don't even know where it comes from.

Comment: Can you show a little more of your code, specifically where that "number" is coming from?  I need a little more info to help you strip the comma out.

Comment: x is the amount
coming from the application, so i dont know what type it is

Comment: Can you show more of your code?  Is this automatically generated code?

Comment: @user175084: If `x` is coming from the application, it sounds like it must initially be a string which is then used to generate the code `round(3,98.9898, 2)` (based on the error message shown in your question).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the comma. In Python to create floating point numbers you use only the point. Commas do many other things!

EDIT: What do you want to do? What is your number?